# How to Order by two properties Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I would like the date to be the priority when sorting, but if the date is the same I need it to be in or of the sequence number lowest first?

```
 Dim ListObj As New List(Of SomeObject)
 ListObj.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Date).ThenBy(Function(x) x.SequenceNumber)
```

Output:

```
2020/11/11 1
2020/11/09 3
2020/11/10 4
2020/11/10 5
2020/11/11 6
2020/11/09 6
```

Expecting:

```
2020/11/09 3
2020/11/09 6
2020/11/10 4
2020/11/10 5
2020/11/11 1
2020/11/11 6
```

Comment: Remember that all LINQ operators return a new `IEnumerable<T>`, so be sure to assign it to a variable. Otherwise you would just be using the original, unsorted list.

Comment: The question doesn't show us the definition of `SomeObject`. Perhaps that is where the problem is.

Comment: @Alejandro you are right I assigned it to a variable and I saw in the result the order that I need how can I get it back to my original collection `ListObj` and if that's not possible, how can I get it back to be of type `SomeObject`?

Comment: ````.ToList()````

Comment: `ListObj = ListObj.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Date).ThenBy(Function(x) x.SequenceNumber).ToList()`

Comment: You don't have to use `ToList` necessarily, but you do need to assign the result to something.  `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` don't modify the original sequence; they return a new sequence.  The code you show does the sort and then throws away the result.

Comment: @Decoder94 - I changed your date format to the ISO international standard.

Comment: It shouldn't need to be said, bu the issue doesn't just affect ordering by two properties. The issue relates to most of the LINQ operators and doesn't matter if they are chained or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, LINQ queries do not affect the original list being queried. You should not expect them to because queries generally don't. If you want to use LINQ as you are then you would need to create a new `List(Of SomeObject)` and replace the existing one:

```vb
ListObj = ListObj.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Date).
                  ThenBy(Function(x) x.SequenceNumber).
                  ToList()
```

A potential problem is that any other references to the original list are unaffected by that. Given that the `List(Of T)` class has its own `Sort` method that will sort the existing list in-place though, there's no need to use LINQ:

```vb
ListObj.Sort(Function(x, y)
                 Dim result = x.Date.CompareTo(y.Date)

                 If result = 0 Then
                     result = x.SequenceNumber.CompareTo(y.SequenceNumber)
                 End If

                 Return result
             End Function)
```

That overload of `Sort` takes a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate to compare pairs of items, so you can write a Lambda or a named method that compares in as simple or as complex a way as you like. The second snippet above is basically how the LINQ will be implemented behind the scenes anyway.